# Grails war file deployment on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, deployment

When I deploy Grails application (war file) on Tomcat 7 I start it with ***server_ip:8080/war_file_name-0.1***
How can I make this server_ip/war_file/

Comment: Perhaps [this discussion](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Changing-URL-for-Deployment-td1360468.html) helps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the name of the war file. You can change the name generated by Grails either by specifying it on the command line:

```
grails war war_file.war
```

or by setting it in `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.war.destFile = "war_file.war"
```

If you want to get rid of the :8080 after the server IP, change the default port that Tomcat listens on to 80.